how dynamically hide or show any tab while using the bottom navigation StatefulShellRoute go_router

I am using the go_router: ^14.2.3 library in my app.
The app has a login screen and a main screen with bottom navigation tabs. Let’s say there are three tabs: Section A, Section B, and Section C.
I’ve implemented my StatefulShellRoute following the go_router documentation. You can take a look at the implementation here https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/main/packages/go_router/example/lib/others/custom_stateful_shell_route.dart
After logging in, I need to show 2 or 3 tabs
How can I dynamically hide Section C from Section A?

How can I dynamically hide Section C from Section A?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
